# MediaPlayer stuck in infinite loop in JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx-2, javafx

I'm trying to retrieve metadata from a JavaFX media player. I have created a class that pulls all of the metadata for a song into dictionary then adds it to a list of other songs' metadata. I've been trying to lock out this list while the metadata is pulling, but every time I add some sort of synchronization object, the media player gets stuck in a loop. Currently, this looks like:

```
        Media track = new Media(f.toURI().toString());          
        MediaPlayer mp = new MediaPlayer(track);
        while(mp.getStatus() != Status.READY) {
            // Wait until ready
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);

            }
            catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();

            }
            System.out.println(mp.getStatus().toString());
            // Check for errors
            if (mp.getError() != null) {
                System.out.println(mp.getError());
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(10000);
                }
                catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();

                }

            }

        }

        // Construct dictionary and add it to this.db
        Hashtable<String, String> entry = new Hashtable<String, String>();
        for (String key : mp.getMedia().getMetadata().keySet()) {
            entry.put(key, mp.getMedia().getMetadata().get(key).toString());

        }
        if (entry != null) {
            entry.put("file_path", mp.getMedia().getSource());
            db.add(entry);
            System.out.println(getByIndex(0).toString());

        }
```

The status printing always prints UNKNOWN, and no errors are ever thrown. Any idea what might be happening here? Thanks!

EDIT- Should have mentioned, the media I am trying to play is MP3 files, which have worked in a different section of my code (So, codecs aren't the problem).

Comment: Yeah, the usual progression is from `UNKNOWN` -> `READY`. It does this in other parts of the code, but for some reason when I check the status above, it stalls on UNKNOWN.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are stalling the JavaFX application thread so it can do anything.

Instead of the while true with thread sleep construct, provide the media player with an [onReady](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/media/MediaPlayer.html#onReadyProperty) handler and query and process the metadata when the player tells you it is ready.